Services getting connection refused error from docker-compose but able to hit from localhost
Funny things happen I run my microservices with docker-compose, my config-server is running at http://localhost:8888 and I'm able to access http://localhost:8888/eureka-server/docker from a web browser or when running eureka-service from the command prompt.
But I'm getting the below error when running the docker-compose up command:
| 2024-04-13T15:45:36.659Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888:org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/eureka-server/docker": Connection refused.

I'm trying to resolve this issue for a while
config-service/application.yml
 server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/xyz/config-repo.git
          username: xyz
          password: xyz

# WARNING: Exposing all management endpoints over http should only be used during development, must be locked down in production!
# WARNING: Exposing all management endpoints over http should only be used during development, must be locked down in production!
management.endpoint.health.show-details: "ALWAYS"
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"

logging:
  level:
    root: info

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: docker
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/xyz/config-repo.git
          username: xyz
          password: xyz

Eureka-server/application.yml
spring.config.import: "configserver:http://localhost:8888"

spring:
  application.name: eureka-server
  cloud.config:
    failFast: true
    retry:
      initialInterval: 3000
      multiplier: 1.3
      maxInterval: 10000
      maxAttempts: 20
    uri: http://localhost:8888
    username: root
    password: root
management:
  security:
    enabled: false

---
spring.config.activate.on-profile: docker

spring.cloud.config.uri: http://config-server:8888

You can find config-repo in https://github.com/kakarot987/config-repo
docker-compose.yml
version: '2.1'

services:

  config-server:
    build: spring-cloud/config-server
    mem_limit: 512m
    networks:
      - my-network
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - ENCRYPT_KEY=my-very-secure-encrypt-key
      - SPRING_SECURITY_USER_NAME=root
      - SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - $PWD/config-repo:/config-repo
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"


  eureka:
    build: spring-cloud/eureka-server
    mem_limit: 512m
    networks:
      - my-network
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - ENCRYPT_KEY=my-very-secure-encrypt-key
      - CONFIG_SERVER_USR=root
      - CONFIG_SERVER_PWD=root
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"

networks:
  my-network:
    name: my-network


Try setting: uri: http://localhost:8888 to uri: http://config-server:8888 docker compose is adding the service name as host.

I tried that out but didn't work I see the problem now. When I start the Eureka service it fetches data from http://localhost:8888 instead of http://config-server:8888.
